# Random disappearance of footer widgets

Tags: widgets

The footer widget disappear on their own after few days even if the website is untouched. This happened 4-5 times before and I don't see any security audit log of widget events nor any malware infected. What could be the cause?

There is no solution from the premium theme developers as they have given the common "Added to bug list" reply.

**Normal footer:**

[image]

**Footer widgets disappeared:**

[image]

I have a [**Development Site**](https://b3em7k.myraidbox.de/de/) for the issue to be checked.

**The least security check:**

[image]   [image]

Adding the code which was added for additional footer columns instead of Theme's default 4.

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'stockie_child_local_enqueue_parent_styles' );

function stockie_child_local_enqueue_parent_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

// Add Footer Columns 5 and 6

function add_additional_footer() {

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => esc_html__( 'Footer column 5', 'stockie' ),
    'id' => 'stockie-sidebar-footer-5',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="title widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => esc_html__( 'Footer column 6', 'stockie' ),
    'id' => 'stockie-sidebar-footer-6',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="title widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
}

add_action( 'widgets_init',  'add_additional_footer');
```

Comment: "Added to bug list" sounds like the theme developers believe that what you are reporting is a bug in their implementation

Comment: Yes but it could be a general cooling comment as they deal with many such tickets and try to move on. I have received that response in other tickets as well, which could have been solved by them.

Comment: No one can tell anything without looking inside. Look at the "widgets_init" functions, also look at the templates where the widgets are added. There might might be some "if" functions.

Comment: @ManojKumar It could be possible to lose widgets because of a PHP error that prevents them to be loaded. My suggestion is enabling debug log and check it after seeing the issue again.

Comment: This question is impossible to address without inclusion of the code that is causing the trouble.

Comment: @cjbj Code added. Unaware of the changes that were made in the child theme.

Comment: @Bikram Please add that as answer. It was close and brought me to the solution. There were two files which were registering the sidebar, one - functions.php, two - copied sidebar.php. Deleted the sidebar.php. I hope there are no more random disappearance.

Comment: Neither the style-handle nor the widget id's appear in the source code of your site. So I guess this code has nothing to do with it.

Comment: It has everything to do with it as Bikram pointed towards the widgets_init.  Please check this: https://prnt.sc/r3fts2 My mistake was not to ask this in a WP Fix it site and giving bounty as the incentive. Is it good that I had shared my dev site login data here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the "widgets_init" functions in your theme. There might be other conditions registered for the widgets.

If the widgets are registered correctly with no other conditions. Next, the best place would be at the template.

Look at the template where the widgets are added. There might be some "if" functions that might be controlling the appearance of widgets.

By the look of your development site, the widgets seem to appear inside a template. Find the template where widgets are added. There is a higher chance the widgets are might be on `sidebar-name.php` or on the `footer.php` or any other. Look at both the child theme and the parent theme. If the child theme is the cause, alter the codes to your need. If the parent theme is the cause, create an exact same copy of the file at the child theme and edit the codes to your need.

Comment: Can't even give bounty to the answer as this was closed! Sorry bro.

Comment: No problem, dude.